# Is there an R-function to extract specific string variables

Tags: html, r

I have a df in R, where one of the columns is long html sting that contains alot of arguments. I want to extract specific values into news columns:

**This is what I have:**

```
name <- c("John", "Max")
bio <- c("<status>1</status><profession>Revisor</professio>", "<status>1</status><born>19.06.1995</born><profession>Tech</professio>" )

df <- data.frame(name, bio)
```

**This is what I want:**

```
name <- c("John", "Max")
status <- c(1,1)
profession <- c("Revisor", "Tech")

df <- data.frame(name, status, profession)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is is possible by using "regular expression" with the R package stringr. Here is an example :

```
library(stringr)
name <- c("John", "Max")
bio <- c("<status>1</status><profession>Revisor</professio>", "<status>1</status><born>19.06.1995</born><profession>Tech</professio>" )

status <- stringr::str_extract_all(bio, pattern = "<status>\\d</status>")
status <- stringr::str_replace_all(status, pattern = "(<status>)(\\d)(</status>)", "\\2")

profession <- stringr::str_extract_all(bio, pattern = "<profession>[:alpha:]*</professio>")
profession <- stringr::str_replace_all(profession, pattern = "(<profession>)([:alpha:]*)(</professio>)", "\\2")

df <- data.frame(name, status, profession)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with `extract`:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  extract(bio,
          into = c("status", "profession"),
          regex = "<status>(\\d+)</status>.*<profession>(\\w+)</professio>")
  name status profession
1 John      1    Revisor
2  Max      1       Tech
```

The `regex` part describes the strings from which elements should be extracted in full, while *capturing* the elements of interest in capture groups defined by `()`.

Alternatively, you can use `str_extract`:

```
library(stringr)
df$status <- str_extract(bio, pattern = "(?<=<status>)\\d+(?=</status>)")
df$profession <- str_extract(bio, pattern = "(?=<profession>)\\w+(?=</professio>)")
```

Here we are making use of lookarounds to *conditionally* match, for example:

- `(?<=<status>)`: positive lookbehind to assert that the match must be *preceded* by the literal string `<status>`
- `\\d+`: one or more digits
- `(?=</status>)`: positive lookahead to assert that the match must be *followed* by the literal string `</status>`